# Logic Question - Double Induction

Tags: logic, induction

I'm confused with the logic of a problem. I'm trying to prove a statement of the form $P(n,k)$ where $1 \leq k\leq n$. Based on the problem it seems natural to use (strong) induction on $n$. Proving the base case is easy, and then when you want to prove
$$P(n,k) \implies P(n+1,k) $$
you need to use $P(n-1,k)$ and $P(n-1,k-1)$, so I though that I needed to do something like double induction on $n$ and $k$. But these wouldn't really work because $k$ is bounded by $n$. Is there a way that I get get around this?

I hope to get some help only with just this information. I really don't want to post the problem because it is a homework problem and I don't want unnecessary help.

Comment: I just realized how I can fix this, since $k$ depends on $n$ my $P$ statement is really only a statement dependent on $n$. So, I only need induction on $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the statement you want to prove.

You can see the statement 
$$\forall n\in\mathbb N, \forall k\in\{1,\dots,n\},P(n,k)$$
as
$$\forall n\in\mathbb N,Q(n)$$
where $$Q(n)=\forall k\in\{1,\dots,n\},P(n,k).$$

Then you show that $Q(1)$ is true and that
$$\forall n\in\mathbb N,Q(n)\implies Q(n+1)$$
to conclude.

Comment: Yes, I realized this after posting the question! I put it as a comment under my question! Thanks for the help anyways!

Comment: Oh xD didn't see it. Answer at the same time lol. It's a pleasure :)